# Got Unable to load client print control error when printing from reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

We have a report  using VS2010 ASP.NET ReportViewer control. After deployed to IIS, when the client clicks the Printer icon in the ReportViewer, he got “Unable to load client print control” error. But if he exports the report to PDF, he can print it. This only happens in one machines, others are fine. Also, we are not using SSRS, so it has nothing to do with SQL Server.

Now my question is how do I fix the problem thrown from the Printer icon. After some research, it seems like install Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 SP1 Redistributable on the client machine will fix the problem. However, when we deploy the web app, we do copy the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll, so I am not sure if we need install the redistributable on the client machine.

I actually suspect the error we got is from IE settings about Microsoft ActiveX control. Does anyone have the similar problem? And can you provide some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Printing in IE from ReportViewer is done via ActiveX control indeed. In order for ActiveX to be able to install correctly user has to be an administrator of his/her local system.

If you really need this this to run automatically - and if it's not against your policy - make that user administrator of his own PC.

Otherwise someone with Admin privileges will have to pre-install the ActiveX on that machine.